# How to list pathname of all files using adb

Tags: adb, files

On most of my devices I'm able to use the find command to get the full pathname of all the files on the device.  However I have two tablets that don't have the find command.

I tried various combinations using the `ls` command, however, it doesn't output path names.  It'll put a directory on line line, then a list of files that are in that directory below the directory name.

The output that I'm trying to get is the same output that you would get using `find` or `locate` on the PC.

An example of the output that I'm trying to get is:

This is output from a Tablet that has the find command:
`adb shell find /sdcard/`

> /sdcard/backups/.SystemConfig /sdcard/backups/.SystemConfig/.cuid
>   /sdcard/backups/.SystemConfig/.cuid2 /sdcard/backups/system
>   /sdcard/backups/system/.confd /sdcard/backups/system/.confd-journal
>   /sdcard/backups/system/.config /sdcard/backups/system/.timestamp
>   /sdcard/backups/apps /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/.nomedia
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-16_06-41-10.wav
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-16_10-36-12.wav
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-16_10-36-17.wav
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-16_14-01-15.wav
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-17_06-42-20.wav
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-17_10-34-25.wav
>   /sdcard/EasyVoiceRecorder/2016-06-19_09-42-31.wav

This is the output using: `shell ls -R /sdcard/`

```
/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.documentsui:
files

/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.documentsui/files:

/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.htmlviewer:
files

/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.htmlviewer/files:

/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.nfc:
files

/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.nfc/files:

/sdcard//Android/data/com.android.providers.calendar:
```

I have been looking at other `adb` commands, but I'm only seeing commands to pull or push files from the device.  I'm not seeing a way to just get the full pathname of all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a workaround resolution of mounting the device using [adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless).

The process is simple.  Install the package which is easily build-ed with the two packages from normal distro repositories(the the package's readme):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev android-tools-adb
```

then mount with:

```
$ adbfs ~/mnt
```

Once mounted the `find` command from the PC can be used to process the files.